# Python: how to Convert a list of tuple to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of tuple like:`[(15932, 2.9, 1), (15430, 3.6, 0), (16712, 10.9, 1), (15890, 6.6, 1)]`, how can I convert this to the following DataFrame structure:

```
15932 2.9 1 

15430 3.6 0 

16712 10.9 1 

15890 6.6 1
```

Comment: You can simply pass that list of tuples to the `DataFrame` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Simple like this, by using the default constructor.

```
pd.DataFrame([(15932, 2.9, 1), (15430, 3.6, 0), (16712, 10.9, 1), (15890, 6.6, 1)])

       0     1  2
0  15932   2.9  1
1  15430   3.6  0
2  16712  10.9  1
3  15890   6.6  1
```

Or by using an alternate constructor.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records([(15932, 2.9, 1), (15430, 3.6, 0), (16712, 10.9, 1), (15890, 6.6, 1)])
```